# pass data from 2D array to arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, lets have a 2D array with size 4*4

```
 int [][] test = {
                 {1,2,3,4},
                 {5,6,7,8},
                 {9,10,11,12},
                 {13,14,15,16},
                 };
```

Then how to pass the 2D array as above to an `ArrayList` and then if i want to print out the 2D array data as the format above, how to do that ?

However, it would be great if someone provide clear explanation.

Comment: And FYI, your *one* line of code won't even compile.

Comment: You can use Arrays.deepToString to print out the 2D Array, to convert it into a List you can make use of for loops. See: https://repl.it/repls/OrderlyThunderousTrace